# Unable to get result of regex expression in pyspark dataframe

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Pyspark in Databricks with Spark 3.1.

I need to extract numbers from a text column in a dataframe using the `regexp_extract_all` function

**Approach 1**:

```
email_df11 = spark.sql("select New_id, regexp_extract_all(subject,'(?<!^DT!\\d)([D|d][T|t]\\d{12}|\\d{9,29})(?!\\d)', 1) as num_subject  from email_view")
```

This results num_subject column with empty lists.

[image: No result]

However when I use a view of the same data frame and run the query below. I am able to see the output.

**Approach 2**:

```sql
select New_id, regexp_extract_all(subject,'same regex as above', 1) as num_subject from email_view
```

[image]

What do I need to change in Approach 1 in order to get a similar result.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use four backslashes `\\\\` to escape when using `spark.sql`:

```
email_df11 = spark.sql("select New_id, regexp_extract_all(subject,'(?<!^DT!\\\\d)([D|d][T|t]\\\\d{12}|\\\\d{9,29})(?!\\\\d)', 1) as num_subject  from email_view")
```

Or use python raw format string for the query:

```
email_df11 = spark.sql(r"select New_id, regexp_extract_all(subject,'(?<!^DT!\\d)([D|d][T|t]\\d{12}|\\d{9,29})(?!\\d)', 1) as num_subject  from email_view")
```